# Regex to match number of students in arbitrary text

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the number of students from a bunch of texts:

- Join 4,400 other students!
- taken by over 7000 students

The ideal result in these cases would be:

- 4,400
- 7000

However, there are many other number present in the texts, so simply matching numbers won't do. A more complete snippet from the text might read:

```
His work has been read by over 350,000 people, and his course "Effortless Output" has been taken by over 7000 students.  

His website is read by over 400,000 people per month.
```

I tried using some simple regex like

```
\d+ other students
```

but this fails if there are thousands separators present in the number.

Comment: Are you hoping to match `400,000` from *His website is read by over 400,000 people per month.* or not?

Comment: No, just the actual number of students.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookahead to match a number, with (optional) properly placed commas, that appear before "student" without intervening digits.

```
(?<!\S)\d+(,\d{3})*\b(?=\D*student)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/958un8foWM6cKN).

This matches `7000`, without matching `350,000`, from

> His work has been read by over 350,000 people, and his course "Effortless Output" has been taken by over 7000 students.

and won't match anything from:

> Bad number 2,22 of students

Answer (score 1):

We can capture the closest number to the student by taking advantage of the greedy form matching of `.*`

```
(?:.*\s)?([\d,]+).*student
```

**Sample**
[image]

Where:

- `(?:.*\s)?` - Match the initial part of the text in a greedy way. This is just optional to take into account cases when the number of students is the first part of the string. The initial part of the string is any character up to a space.
- `([\d,]+)` - Capture the number part. Since the next match is to find "student" while the earlier match is any character in greedy way, this will be the closest number to the "student" word.
- `.*` - Match any character
- `student` - Match the "student" word

Answer (score 0):

How about: `(:?\d+|\d+,\d+)\sstudent`?

Instead of `\s` one probably would have to scan, when there are variations.